# Flask, CSS file not registering on routes

Tags: css, flask

I am new to Programming in general. Hence this 'repeated question' as I don't understand the answers given on other posts. (Just incase, I have tried `command-shift-R`, but it won't work. It just displays a grey screen. I would genuinely appreciate if you guys could direct me towards the right way as I've spent a good whole day trying to figure out why my `main.css` file won't update the webpage. Everything else is working. Apart from when trying to update the stylesheet of the webpage.

My project is to create a website through Flask. I have created my necessary `@app.route(...)`'s.
I am importing the following on my `app.py` file: `from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for`. Everything within my `app.py` file and `templates` folder works. The output of a basic webpage with a few bullet points and header is displayed.

My `templates` folder which includes `layout.html` consists of the following code:
`

```
        <!--Stylesheet is linking to main.css file within static folder.
            'url_for' function is taking care to find the exact location.-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">

        <!--The following 'if' statement determine what is displayed on the browser Tab.
            The Default title is 'Intellectus' which is in the 'else'.-->
        {% if title %}
            <title>Intellectus - {{ title }}</title>
        {% else %}
            <title>Intellectus</title>
        {% endif %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Top Navigation Bar-->
        <!--Intellectus text-Homepage-->
    <nav class="navbar-full">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Intellectus</a>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">User Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="sign-up"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`
```

My `static` folder includes a `css` folder which includes a `main.css` folder. It's basic stuff for now just to get something working. The code within `main.css` is below:

```css
.navbar-full {
    background-color: #00BFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container-fluid a {
    float: left;
    color: #00BFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.container-fluid a:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: forestgreen;
}

.body {
    background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I was using Safari browser instead of Chrome. Worked like a charm in Chrome.
Not sure what exactly was causing the problem with the Safari browser.